# Bash to Grep and Exclude At the Same Time Using Regex

Tags: regex, bash, debian

I want to grep a string from command output but remove a substring at the same time. For instance

String = **Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-03-12 20:02:20 PKT; 1h 31min ago**

What I want = **active (running) since 20:02:20 PKT**

Removed

1. Active:
2. Sat 2022-03-12
3. ; 1h 31min ago

To do that I have been using regular expression initially

`sudo service sshd status |grep -Po '(?<=Active: )(.*) since (.*);'`

`active (running) since Mon 2022-03-14 01:06:43 PKT;`

Can you tell how can i ignore date as well as last semi-colon ; while keeping the time only and have output exactly like:

`active (running) since 01:06:43 PKT`

Thanks

Full output of command:

````
● xrdp.service - xrdp daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-03-14 01:06:44 PKT; 3 days ago
     Docs: man:xrdp(8)
           man:xrdp.ini(5)
  Process: 668 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh /usr/share/xrdp/socksetup (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 682 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/xrdp $XRDP_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 687 (xrdp)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/xrdp.service
           └─687 /usr/sbin/xrdp

systemd[1]: Starting xrdp daemon...
xrdp[682]: (682)(-1224841088)[DEBUG] Testing if xrdp can listen on 0.0.0.0 port 3389.
xrdp[682]: (682)(-1224841088)[DEBUG] Closed socket 7 (AF_INET6 :: port 3389)
systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Can't open PID file /run/xrdp/xrdp.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory```
````

Comment: You can remove the semi-colon with `grep -Po '(?<=Active: )(.*) since (.*)(?=;)'` but for the date in the middle of the pattern you've reached GNU grep limitations, so you'll have to append something like `| sed 's/since [^ ]* [^ ]*/since/'` to the command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -nE 's/^ *Active: +(.* since ).*([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}[^;]*).*/\1\2/p'
```

*Details*:

- `-nE` - `n` suppresses default line output and `E` enables the POSIX ERE regex syntax
- `^Active: +(.* since ).*([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}[^;]*).*` - finds lines matching

  - `^ *Active: +` - start of string, zero or more spaces, `Active:` and one or more spaces
  - `(.* since )` - Group 1 (`\1`): any text and then space + `since` + space
  - `.*` - any text
  - `([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}[^;]*)` - two digits, `:`, two digits, `:`, two digits, and then any zero or more chars other than `;`
  - `.*` - the rest of the string
- `\1\2` - concatenated Group 1 and 2 values
- `p` - `p`rints the result of the substitution.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/ECfG8z):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='   Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-03-12 20:02:20 PKT; 1h 31min ago'
sed -nE 's/^ *Active: +(.* since ).*([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}[^;]*).*/\1\2/p' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
active (running) since 20:02:20 PKT
```

Comment: Strangely when string is stored in variable, it gives correct output. When used with command, it do not work. `sudo service xrdp status | sed -nE 's/^Active: +(.* since ).*([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}[^;]*).*/\1\2/p'` Gives no output although same string is contained in multi-line command output. I have added full command output in question for your reference.

Comment: @BilalBhatti Because there are spaces at the start of the line. I added ``' *'`` after `^` in the regex and it works now.

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes the output is like 

`Active: inactive (dead)`

How can we have one regex to handle both?

Comment: @BilalBhatti And what then? Is it expected? What is the *input*? Try `sed -nE 's/^ *Active: +(.* since ).*([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}[^;]*).*|.*(Active: inactive \(dead\)).*/\1\2\3/p'`

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`. Simple explanation would be, creating a shell variable named `val` and sending its value to `awk` then in `awk` program I am using `match` function to match regex to get required value.

```
val="Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-03-12 20:02:20 PKT; 1h 31min ago"
echo "$val"  | 
awk '
match($0,/^Active:[[:space:]]+active \(running\)[[:space:]]+.*[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}[[:space:]]+([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}[^;]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/^Active:[[:space:]]+/,"",val)
  sub(/since[[:space:]]+\S+\s+\S+/,"since",val)
  print val
}
'
```

***Explanation of regex:***

```
^Active:[[:space:]]+       ##Matching value starting from Active: followed by space(s).
active \(running\)         ##matching active followed by a space followed by (running).
[[:space:]]+.*[0-9]{4}     ##Matching 1 or more spaces then using greedy match to match 4 occurrences of digits.
(-[0-9]{2}){2}             ##Matching - followed by 2 digits and this whole combination 2 times.
[[:space:]]+([0-9]{2}:){2} ##Matching space(s) followed by 2 digits followed by colon and this whole combination 2 times.
[0-9]{2}[^;]*              ##Matching 2 digits and everything after it till a semi-colon comes.
```